# Applying differencing for time series data before regression analysis

Tags: regression, time-series, importance, differencing

I am new to time series regression. I am trying to understand the effect of differencing the time-dependent data before applying regression analysis.

I tried fitting lots of regression models but in all those cases the model assumptions are violated and show a high autocorrelation.

I was told that interpretation of the model is extremely hard when differencing is applied. But my objective is to determine the variable importance; therefore I want to understand whether applying differencing has an effect on variable importance.

What other methods can I use to understand variable importance in time series variable?

Comment: Hi Nipuni. Welcome to CV. Could you elucidate which model assumptions you are talking about? What is the motivation of (not) differencing before applying regression? Any elaboration would be appreciated.

Comment: About the interpretation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74924/interpreting-coefficients-of-first-differences-of-logarithms

Comment: Hello, So when I applied regression analysis on the data, Normality assumption, multicollinearity, and all residual analysis assumptions were violated. I tried applying transformations like log transformations and square root transformations but still, the models did not satisfy the assumptions. In all the models, residuals showed a high autocorrelation. My teacher suggested using a variable selection method, so I applied the backward selection method and also tried all possible models method but still a satisfying model cannot be found because of the autocorrelation.

Comment: There's a trend pattern in the data, therefore I used differencing on the data and then applied regression then the model assumptions were all satisfied. But I'm not sure if that is a valid, meaningful method.

Comment: @NipuniOpatha, unless we get a glimpse of your data, it is too speculative to give a substantial answer. Meanwhile, you can check the site for related posts like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279397/when-is-first-differences-for-time-series-trend-removal-appropriate-to-use), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27691/how-do-i-interpret-my-regression-with-first-differenced-variables), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194259/time-series-regression-coefficient-interpretation-with-differenced-independent-v), (ctd.)

Comment: [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23704/time-series-regression-serially-correlated-errors-vs-autocorrelation-of-residua), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430395/handling-serial-correlation-in-time-series-regression), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325706/stationarity-time-series-vs-regression) etc.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods, Thank you very much for the help. I will look up those posts.